# ¿Puedo usar el metodo PUT en un formulario html?

Tags: html5, http

Hasta el momento todo va bien con GET o POST con un formulario HTML, pero se puede usar PUT, PATCH, UPDATE para usarlos como method al enviar el formulario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo a esta otra respuesta en [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054241/1305745), esto no es posible
ya que solo `GET` y `POST` son los métodos permitidos por la [definición de la W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#form-control-infrastructure-form-submission):

> The method and formmethod content attributes are enumerated attributes
>   with the following keywords and states:
>
> - The keyword get, mapping to the state GET, indicating the HTTP GET
>     method.
> - The keyword post, mapping to the state POST, indicating the
>     HTTP POST method.
> - The keyword dialog, mapping to the state dialog,
>     indicating that submitting the form is intended to close the dialog
>     box in which the form finds itself, if any, and otherwise not submit.

Se menciona un tercer, "dialog", pero no es comunmente usado. De acuerdo a los [Usage Notes de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) su funcionalidad si esta implementada:

> form elements can be integrated within a dialog by specifying them with the attribute method="dialog". When such a form is submitted, the dialog is closed with a returnValue attribute set to the value of the submit button used.